# strange behavior of & and ^ in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, twos-complement

Here are my code and wondering why different results in both cases? Actually I expect first line output -1, since bit AND 0xffffffff does not change anything. And I expect second line output 1, since bit XOR 0xffffffff means bit NOT (which is `~` in Python, and adding another 1 should gets -1's two's complement value, which is 1)

```
print -1 & 0xffffffff # output 4294967295
print -1 ^ 0xffffffff + 1 # output -4294967297
```

Comment: Python integer arithmetic is not 32-bit; it is infinite-bit. (It doesn't physically store an infinite number of bits, but it behaves like it does.)

Comment: @user2357112, I understand it is infinite like Java big integer, but how it comes to value 4294967295 in my first case and -4294967297 in my second case?

Comment: Your reasoning is assuming 32-bit. Why do you think "bit AND 0xffffffff does not change anything"? Why do you think "bit XOR 0xffffffff means bit NOT"?

Comment: (If you tested this in Java and got -1 and 1, you most likely screwed up the precedence of `^` and `+` and the initialization of the 0xffffffff BigInteger. With correct precedence and avoiding overflow on 0xffffffff, [Java gives the same output](http://ideone.com/A8S8jf).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python implements integers with arbitrary precision. When performing bit-wise operations, positive numbers are treated as if they have an infinite sequence of high-order `0` bits, while negative numbers act like they have an infinite sequence of high-order `1` bits. In particular, the number `-1` acts like an infinite sequence of `1`'s.

So for the first calculation we have

```
    ...11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
  & ...00000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111
  = ...00000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111
```

Since this has `0` in the high-order bits, it's a positive result.

The second calculation is:

```
    ...11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
  ^ ...00000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000 (this is 0xffffffff + 1 = 0x100000000)
  = ...11111111111111111111111011111111111111111111111111111111
```

Since this has `1` in the high-order bits, it's a negative result.

Comment: That doesn't yet explain the outcome in full. Note that [`+` binds stronger than `^`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in Python, hence the second example reduces to `-1 ^  0x100000000`.

Comment: Thanks, missed the `+1`. I've updated the answer to show that.

Comment: @dhke Also corrected the number of low-order digits.

Comment: 32bits are really A LOT when one needs to type them out.

Comment: Thanks for the help Barmar, mark your reply as answer.